# Using batch commands to create folders and copy filenames

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I want to copy all files on a list to another location and create sub-folders in that location based on certain attributes of the filenames. In this case, the company names. All files are currently located in desktop\main.

For example, lets say the list has filenames like

```
From((Sales@JonesCompany.com))main.txt
From((AR@PeterIndustries.com))main.txt
From((AP@BaseCorporation.com))main.txt
```

The script should copy those files, make a directory like JonesCompany.com, and finally copy all respective filenames to that location.

The end result should be like

```
desktop\final_location\JonesCompany\
desktop\final_location\PeterIndustries\
desktop\final_location\BaseCorporation\
```

So far I have

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (main.txt) do echo F|xcopy "C:\Users\Desktop\Main\%%i" MD %%i "C:\Users\Desktop\final_location\%%i" /i /z /y
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this does what you want:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "basepath=C:\Users\Desktop\Main\"
set "filter=*.txt"
set "targetpath=C:\Users\Desktop\final_location\"
echo scanning %basepath%%filter%
for %%i in ("%basepath%%filter%") do (
    for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=@)" %%a in ("%%i") do (
        echo Creating Folder %%b...
        mkdir %basepath%%%b\
        echo copying file %%i to %targetpath%%%b\...
        copy "%%i" %targetpath%%%b\
    )
)
```

You can easily change the `basepath`, `targetpath` and `filter` variables as needed.

**Explanation**
The trickiest part is `for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=@)" %%a in ("%%i") do (`.  `%%i` is a filename. Let's say it's `From((Sales@JonesCompany.com))main.txt`.  This `for` statement will split the string at any instance of the delimiters `@` or `)`.  This leaves us with the following array of strings:

1. `%%a`: "From((Sales"
2. `%%b`: "JonesCompany.com"
3. `%%c`: NULL (I think)
4. `%%d`: "main.txt"

Obviously, we want `%%b` so we use it as the new folder name.  We then copy `%%i`, the original full path, to the new folder.

**update** removed a loop thanks to [@Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) pointing out something I didn't realize!

Comment: I just realized I overlooked the part about the list.  This answer just reads all the filenames from the /main/ directory.  Based on your sample code, you should be able to adapt it to a list if necessary.

Comment: `delims=))` ?  Delimiters are single chars only.

Comment: similar in `for /?` (`delims=xxx`)

Comment: still works as single chars: delimiters are `)` and `)` , not "two `)`"

Comment: No problem. You were right, `))` would have worked exactly like `)`, but would have set wrong expectations for future readers.

Comment: Works great if there are no spaces with the basepath filename. For example, From((Sales@JonesCompany.com))main.txt copied over but From((Sales@JonesCompany.com))main 10.txt did not. Also, I changed mkdir %basepath% to %targetpath%. Weird that the variable does not account for spaces.

Comment: Try putting quotes around `%%i` in the copy statement